# searching two tables with sphinx and or mysql?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have two tables.  One for artists (artist_id, artist_name), one for tracks (track_id, artist_id, track_title).

I want to be able to handle queries like "better man pearl jam" but I'm having trouble thinking about the logic on how this would work.  better man is the track title while pearl jam is the artist name.

We're currently using sphinx to handle our search engine (artists and tracks individually).

is there an efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that if someone does a search that matches both track and artist, they're looking for the track. What is your desired behaviour in this case?

Based on your comment, your sphinx query should look like this then:

```
SELECT track_id, track_title, artists.artist_id, artist_name FROM tracks
LEFT JOIN artists WHERE artists.artist_id = tracks.artist_id;
```

If you're using PHP, your code would look something like:

$res = $sc->Query($searchString, "SphinxIndexName");

```
if (isset($res['matches']) && sizeof($res['matches']) > 0) {
  ids = join(",", array_keys($res["matches"]));
  $query = "SELECT track_id, track_title, artists.artist_id, artist_name FROM tracks
    LEFT JOIN artists WHERE artists.artist_id = tracks.artist_id ORDER BY FIELD(track_id, $ids)";
   // ... query MySQL and display results
}
else {
   echo "no results";
}
```

Comment: To do exactly that, show the track result.  only show better man where artist is pearl jam.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm confused too.  Which index do I hit?  The track index, the artist index or both?  Am I creating a new index to handle this?  And would your logic work in reverse: pearl jam better man

Comment: The logic would work either way.  Your goal is to match based on keywords, not the order of the keywords, and sphinx does that well.  Your main unit in this scenario will usually be tracks, and you'll only use the artist index to do things like looking for tracks by specific artists.  Post your sphinx config here as well as your code for more help.